# Apache Superset Link

Tags: apache-superset

When I download a table in Supersette with export excel, the columns with links in my table are downloaded openly like example. But I want to download it as a clickable link as I mentioned in the image below.

[This is what Supersette looks like.]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bznVu.png)

[When exported to Excel]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1xGO.png)

Is there any way to do that?